# Prove that the set of matrices is a group in relation with matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, group-theory

[image: The Problem]

The matrixes should be of that form where n is element of integers. I am having problems proving the closed condition as it is only fulfilled when n+m=1 and also the neutral element of course makes no sense as for matrixes it is the E matrix but the 1 at position e(01) doesn’t match.

Comment: Your argument shows correctly that this set of matrices is not a group under matrix multiplication. Are you sure you have the question right?

Comment: Yes I am sure, if you say that the arguments are correct then never in my entire life have I seen a book trolling me, usually when the problem says prove something, there is usually a proof :D Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the book? Can you post the exact exercise? Are you sure it's not the matrices with rows $1, n$ and $0,1$? (In general I prefer "prove or disprove" questions to those that just ask for a proof.)

Comment: Yes the exercise is correctly written the corrected version you proposed is also included in the book. It’s my university professor’s book, not a well known one so mistakes may have slipped away.

Comment: I think you should politely ask your instructor about this possible error. If it is one s/he will be glad you found it.